# Grouping Multiple Datasets using SSRS 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to group Multiple tables with different datasets together. I have searched for this in google and a lot of response mention, that this is not possible. But there should be a way round. Can I use some sort of group expression, which can split into two different groups. I am really not sure. Cna you just point me in the right direction. I am really confused.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you try grouping the datasets themselves together?

Comment: Do you mean grouping the datasets in SQL or in SSRS? @NickyvV

Comment: Yes, I meant in SQL, something like combine the queries?

Comment: Is there a lookup function in ssrs 2005? @NickyvV

Comment: I will try the SQL way of doing it and see if i can do it @NickyvV

Comment: The `Lookup` function isn't available in SSRS until Sql server 2008 R2. You'll need to use SQL to do this. If you have specific questions about how to structure the SQL, please edit your question or create a new question with details.